# How does printf or iostream specify maximum number of digits after the point

Tags: c++, c, c++11

What format string in `printf` or `iomanip` operator in iostream should I use to print the float in the following format:

- 125.0 => 125
- 125.1 => 125.1
- 125.12312 => 125.12
- 1.12345 => 1.12
- 1234.1235 => 1234.12

In short, print at most 2 digits after the point, but remove all trailing zeros.

I tried `%.2f` but doesn't work because it prints 125.00 and 125.10 for the first 2 cases.

Comment: You can only set the absolute precision IIRC, not the maximum precision. It's `std::setprecision(...)` for iostreams btw.

Comment: @Xeo, then is there any simple work around, if I didn't stick to printf or iomanip?  I don't want to process the string and remove trailing zeros myself though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I figured out some simple work around:

```
void print(float f) {
  f = floor(f * 100.0f + 0.5f) / 100.0f;
  cout << f;
}
```

would solve most common cases.  One thing that can't to solved is f > 10e7, which cout will print f in scientific notion.

Comment: You could also use `iostream` with `fixed` and `stringstream`s to print to a string, and then use string manipulation to remove trailing zeros. Then print the final string. It would be inefficient, but it would do what you want.

Comment: I'm doing this too, there's nothing easier in C++ I think. By the way I discovered that the number 135.545 will not be rounded 135.55 but 135.54 and when you try with another number e.g. 125.545 it will be rounded to 125.55 and not 125.54. If someone knows why, tell me, this is not related to C++ especially because the same happens in JavaScript ;) you can try: console.log(Math.round(135.545 * 100) / 100);

Comment: @baptx, I think this is related to how floating point numbers are represented in computer.  I think in computer, numbers like 0.1 can't be precisely represented using binary numbers.  For example, 1/3=0.33333.... can't be precisely represented in decimal because 3 is not a multiplication of 2 and 5 (10=2*5).  The same holds true for 1/10 in binary representation because 5 is not a power of 2.  Therefore the problem you observe probably because 135.545 is probably 135.54500001 in computer and 125.545 is 125.54499999

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to specify that.  You can specify an exact number of digits after the decimal place (so that it adds zeros if needed), or a maximum number of significant digits, but not a maximum number of digits after the decimal place.

NOTE: Xeo answered this first in a comment.

Comment: So any other work around, if I didn't stick to printf or iomanip?

Answer (score 1):

iostream uses [flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/).

Specifically, use `std::cout << std::setprecision(5)` to set the precision to 5. See [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) and [ios_base::precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/).

If you set the precision, without setting [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/), it will use the precision you specify without trailing zeros. If you also set the `fixed` flag, it will print trailing zeros up to the precision you specify.

printf also uses its own flags. See [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for how to use it.

Comment: Can you show me some example?  I tried using it but doesn't work.

Comment: There is no maximum, and we regularly use `17` (which is needed if you want to ensure round trip).

Comment: @icando `double almostpi = 3.1415926535897932384; std::cout << std::setprecision(6); std::cout << almostpi;` should print `3.14159`.

Comment: @icando `double almostpi = 3.14; std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed; std::cout << almostpi;` should print `3.140000000`.

Comment: @James Kanze ah, thanks. I realized why I thought 15 was the maximum--it's the max precision of the coordinate objects I regularly deal with. Heh.

Comment: setprecision without fixed sets the maximum number of significant digits and not the number of digits after the decimal place.  So 1234.1235 gets printed as 1.2e+03 when using precision 2 and not fixed.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato correct. But `fixed` will _always_ print trailing zeros. As far as I know, there is no way to set an iostream to display with a set precision, to never use scientific notation, and also automatically trim trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default floating point behavior for an iostream.  Just set the precision to the maximum number of digits (5 in your example), and output to the stream normally.

Comment: He is wanting to set a maximum number of digits after the decimal place, not a maximum number of total digits.

Comment: @VaughnCato I have no idea what he actually wants to see.  He doesn't say; he only provides a few examples.  What is clear, I think, is that he doesn't want any trailing `0` after the decimal, and that he doesn't want more than 2 digits after the decimal if there are 3 before: whether that means 5 digits total, or 2 after the decimal, I don't know.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I did say "In short, print at most 2 digits after the point, but remove all trailing zeros." when I initially post this.  I only added a few examples later on.

Comment: @icando Yes.  I see it now.  For some reason, I just saw the examples, and since it is a frequent problem.  In this case, I think you're stuck with doing a lookup based on the value in order to determine what the precision should be: value between 0 and 1, precision 2, between 1 and 10, 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char buf[5];
int l = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2f", x);
if (!strcmp(buf, "0.00")) printf("0\n");
else printf("%.*g\n", l-1, x);
```

Answer (score -1):

The `printf` family has the `%g` format for that purpose (but it also has another purpose to change the %f in %e in some cases). As James point out, it is the default behavior with C++ IOStream; to reset it if it has been changed to something else:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%.2g %.2g\n", 1.2, 0.0000012);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 1.2 << " " << 0.0000012 << '\n';
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed|std::ios_base::scientific, std::ios_base::floatfield);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << 1.2 << " " << 0.0000012 << '\n';
}
```

gives

```
1.2 1.2e-06
1.20 0.00
1.2 1.2e-06
```

Comment: Can you show me some example? I tried using it but doesn't work.

Comment: %.2g doesn't fit my needs. 125 is printed as 1.2e+02