# I need to round an output and show xxx.0 for an assignment in C++

Tags: c++, cmath, ceil

Can I get some help with my assignment? I had to create a BMI Calculator that takes in test cases and produce a bmi with one decimal place. My code passes most cases but one, where feet = 4, inches = 10, and pounds = 1000. The expected outcome is 209.0 and I can only get 209 to be output, do I just have to make an if statement and add in the ".0" or is there a way to code it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double feet, inches, pounds, bmi;

    cout << "== BMI Calculator ==" << endl;

    cout << "Step 1: Enter height" << endl;
    cout << "Feet:" << endl;
    cin >> feet;
    cout << "Inches:" << endl;
    cin >> inches;
    cout << "Step 2: Enter weight" << endl;
    cout << "Pounds:" << endl;
    cin >> pounds;

    inches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    bmi = ((pounds * 703) / (inches * inches));
    bmi = ceil(bmi * 10) / 10;

    cout << "BMI: " << bmi << endl;

    if (bmi < 18.5)
        cout << "you are underweight." << endl;
    else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)
        cout << "you are normal." << endl;
    else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9)
        cout << "you are overweight." << endl;
    else
        cout << "you are obese." << endl;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does printf or iostream specify maximum number of digits after the point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588517/how-does-printf-or-iostream-specify-maximum-number-of-digits-after-the-point)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a formatting issue.  Look here:

- http://arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html
- http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/28-3.html
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/

EXAMPLE:

```
  double f = 3.14159;
  cout.unsetf(ios::floatfield);            // floatfield not set
  cout.precision(5);
```

OUTPUT:

```
3.1416
```

Comment: Thank you for the resources, I guess I was looking for cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(1);